# Change elements order in Angular's ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to change elements order depending on some condition while doing `ng-repeat`?

Suppose we have such a code:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">
   <div class="element-1">Element 1: {{i}}</div>
   <div class="element-2">Element 2: {{i}}</div>
</div>
```

Now I would like change order of `element-*`  `divs` when `i` is even. Is it possible?

Output:

```
<div>
   <div class="element-1">Element 1: 1</div>
   <div class="element-2">Element 2: 1</div>
</div>

<div>
   <div class="element-2">Element 2: 2</div>
   <div class="element-1">Element 1: 2</div>
</div>

<div>
   <div class="element-1">Element 1: 3</div>
   <div class="element-2">Element 2: 3</div>
</div>

<div>
   <div class="element-2">Element 2: 4</div>
   <div class="element-1">Element 1: 4</div>
</div>
```

... etc.

**[edit]**

I would like to avoid a solution of adding `float: right` for `element-1`.

I would also like to avoid repeating the HTML code (creating the second block). This is a simple sample of my problem. My project is a far more complicated (tons of code).

Comment: You could use two different containers and `ng-hide` on alternating containers with something like `ng-hide="i%2==0"`

Answer (score 0):

Use two separate containers with `ng-hide` or `ng-if` to achieve what you want:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">
   <div ng-if="i % 2 == 0">
       <div class="element-1">Element 1: {{i}}</div>
       <div class="element-2">Element 2: {{i}}</div>
   </div>
   <div ng-if="i % 2 != 0">
       <div class="element-2">Element 2: {{i}}</div>
       <div class="element-1">Element 1: {{i}}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use ng-if over ng-show/ng-hide since it keeps your DOM smaller and cleaner. you have to beware of possible scope issues with ng-if though

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">

   <div class="element-1" ng-if="$index % 2 === 0">Element 1: {{i}}</div>
   <div class="element-2" ng-if="$index % 2 === 0">Element 2: {{i}}</div>

   <div class="element-2" ng-if="$index % 2 === 1">Element 2: {{i}}</div>
   <div class="element-1" ng-if="$index % 2 === 1">Element 1: {{i}}</div>

</div>
```